# How to make one dropdown invisible or display:none when the other dropdown is on a certain selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropdown

I have 2 dropdowns - one for state, one for city. I want to make it so that, when the State dropdown is on the default selected value (`--State--`), the City dropdown is not even visible. But otherwise, as long as you select any of the states, the dropdown box will be there.

My current code is such that the 'City' options change depending on what 'State' you have selected. For reasons I don't understand, this JSFiddle isn't working, but it's working in Brackets. http://jsfiddle.net/a70zjg9p/4/

I just need help implementing:

```
if --State-- (default value) is selected, make City dropdown invisible
```

code on top of the code I already have.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var optarray = $("#layout_select").children('option').map(function() {
    return {
      "value": this.value,
      "option": "<option value='" + this.value + "'>" + this.text + "</option>"
    }
  })

  $("#column_select").change(function() {
    $("#layout_select").children('option').remove();
    var addoptarr = [];
    for (i = 0; i < optarray.length; i++) {
      if (optarray[i].value.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1) {
        addoptarr.push(optarray[i].option);
      }
    }
    $("#layout_select").html(addoptarr.join(''))
  }).change();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="column_select" id="column_select" style="height:35px;" class="required" title=" * Please provide your location">
  <option selected value="col0">-- State --</option>
  <option value="col1">Alabama</option>
  <option value="col2">Florida</option>
  <option value="col3">Texas</option>
</select>
<select name="layout_select" id="layout_select" style="height:35px;">
  <option value="col0">-- City --</option>
  <option value="col1">Montgomery</option>
  <option value="col2">Orlando</option>
  <option value="col3">Dallas</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `this.outerHTML` would probably be a better way to populate `option`.

Comment: I don't see anything in your javascript that would make the layout_select not display.  I do see logic that empties it of options.

Comment: Also, as I've shown in my answer, it is not necessary to re-create the options every time.  You can simply detach them and re-attach the ones that you need.  This saves you from having to generate elements repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comments in the logic below for details on what it is doing at each step.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //get the cities and detach them, since state presumably starts
  //as --State--
  var $citySelect = $("#layout_select");
  var $cities = $citySelect.children().detach();

  $("#column_select").on('change', function(e) {
    //remove any cities that were previously re-attached
    $cities.detach();
    
    if (e.target.value === 'col0') {
      //col0 is --State--, hide the cities
      $citySelect.hide();
    } else {
      //find all the cities for the state and re-attach them
      $citySelect.append(
        $cities.filter(function(){ return this.value === e.target.value })
      );
    
      //show the cities
      $citySelect.show();
    }
  }).change();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="column_select" id="column_select" style="height:35px;" class="required" title=" * Please provide your location">
  <option selected value="col0">-- State --</option>
  <option value="col1">Alabama</option>
  <option value="col2">Florida</option>
  <option value="col3">Texas</option>
</select>



<select name="layout_select" id="layout_select" style="height:35px;">
  <option value="col0">-- City --</option>
  <option value="col1">Montgomery</option>
  <option value="col2">Orlando</option>
  <option value="col3">Dallas</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the selected value of the first select, if it is equal to `col0`, then hide the second select, if not, show it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var optarray = $("#layout_select").children('option').map(function() {
            return {
                "value": this.value,
                "option": "<option value='" + this.value + "'>" + this.text + "</option>"
            }
        })
            
        $("#column_select").change(function() {            
            var addoptarr = [];
            var citySelect = $("#layout_select");
            for (i = 0; i < optarray.length; i++) {
                if (optarray[i].value.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1) {
                    addoptarr.push(optarray[i].option);
                }
            }
            citySelect.html(addoptarr.join(''))

            //CHECK IF IS EQUAL TO 'col0'
            if (this.value == "col0"){
              citySelect.hide();
            }else{
              citySelect.show();
            }
        }).change();
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="column_select" id="column_select" style="height:35px;" class="required" title=" * Please provide your location">
        <option selected value="col0">-- State --</option>    
        <option value="col1">Alabama</option>    
        <option value="col2">Florida</option>    
        <option value="col3">Texas</option>    
    </select>
    
    
    
    <select name="layout_select" id="layout_select" style="height:35px; display: none">
        <option value="col0">-- City --</option>    
        <option value="col1">Montgomery</option>
        <option value="col2">Orlando</option>
        <option value="col3">Dallas</option>
    </select>
```

As you can see `if (this.value == ...)` I'm using `this` because in the current context (the `change` trigger of the element), `this` is equivalent to the element, in this case, the `select`

Answer (score 1):

Just check the text of the selected option of the select and hide `#layout_select` if it is equal to `"-- State --"`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var optarray = $("#layout_select").children('option').map(function() {
            return {
                "value": this.value,
                "option": "<option value='" + this.value + "'>" + this.text + "</option>"
            }
        })
         $('#layout_select').hide();
        $("#column_select").change(function() {
            $("#layout_select").children('option').remove();
            var addoptarr = [];
            for (i = 0; i < optarray.length; i++) {
                if (optarray[i].value.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1) {
                    addoptarr.push(optarray[i].option);
                }
            }
            $("#layout_select").html(addoptarr.join(''));
            if($('#column_select').find(":selected").text()=="-- State --"){
        $('#layout_select').hide();
     } else {
       $('#layout_select').show();
     }
        }).change();
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="column_select" id="column_select" style="height:35px;" class="required" title=" * Please provide your location">
        <option selected value="col0">-- State --</option>    
        <option value="col1">Alabama</option>    
        <option value="col2">Florida</option>    
        <option value="col3">Texas</option>    
    </select>
    
    
    
    <select name="layout_select" id="layout_select" style="height:35px;">
        <option value="col0">-- City --</option>    
        <option value="col1">Montgomery</option>
        <option value="col2">Orlando</option>
        <option value="col3">Dallas</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

if i have understood correctly, when the first option is selected (--State--), then the you need to hide the city dropdown...

in order to do that, you can use the following script:

http://jsfiddle.net/a70zjg9p/10/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $state = $("#column_select"),
    $city = $("#layout_select");

  $city.hide();

  $state.on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "col0") {
      $city.hide();
    } else {
      $city.show();
    }
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="column_select" id="column_select" style="height:35px;" class="required" title=" * Please provide your location">
  <option selected value="col0">-- State --</option>
  <option value="col1">Alabama</option>
  <option value="col2">Florida</option>
  <option value="col3">Texas</option>
</select>



<select name="layout_select" id="layout_select" style="height:35px;display:none">
  <option value="col0">-- City --</option>
  <option value="col1">Montgomery</option>
  <option value="col2">Orlando</option>
  <option value="col3">Dallas</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Tut114</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .Hide {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var optarray = $("#layout_select").children('option').map(function () {
                return {
                    "value": this.value,
                    "option": "<option value='" + this.value + "'>" + this.text + "</option>"
                }
            })
            $("#column_select").change(function () {
                if ($('#column_select option:selected').text() != "-- State --") {
                    $("#layout_select").removeClass("Hide");

                    $("#layout_select").children('option').remove();
                    var addoptarr = [];
                    for (i = 0; i < optarray.length; i++) {
                        if (optarray[i].value.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1) {
                            addoptarr.push(optarray[i].option);
                        }
                    }
                    $("#layout_select").html(addoptarr.join(''))
                }
                else {
                    $("#layout_select").addClass("Hide");
                }
            }).change();
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="column_select" id="column_select" style="height:35px;" class="required" title=" * Please provide your location">
        <option selected value="col0">-- State --</option>
        <option value="col1">Alabama</option>
        <option value="col2">Florida</option>
        <option value="col3">Texas</option>
    </select>
    <select name="layout_select" id="layout_select" style="height:35px;">
        <option value="col0">-- City --</option>
        <option value="col1">Montgomery</option>
        <option value="col2">Orlando</option>
        <option value="col3">Dallas</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```